# Difference between READ_LOGS and READ_CALL_LOG permissions of android

Tags: android, android-permissions, calllog

What is the difference between below 2 set of permission?

1)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

2)

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.logsprovider.permission.WRITE_LOGS" />
```

Comment: Can the down voter kindly comment why the question is down voted? I would like to know that what is being wrong that my question is down voted. It would help us only to be good at asking question on SO next time..

Comment: Most probably because the answer can be looked up on search engines too easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `READ_CALL_LOG` -- Allows an application to read the user's call log.
- `READ_LOGS` -- Allows an application to read the low-level system log
  files

The first one is mostly specific to phone calls, while the second one is for any and all usage of the device.

Comment: So READ_LOGS will access DEBUG/INFO LOGS not the PHONE CALL LOGS? Is it like that?